# RegCreateKeyExW not creating keys

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, registry

I am attempting to create registry keys under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive. I am leveraging the `RegCreateKeyExW`function. I have read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexw) for the function, and believe I am calling it correctly. However, the return value is not `ERROR_SUCCESS` as the code within an the if statement catching failures is being executed. When calling `GetLastError`, the error text states that the operation had been executed successfully. When checking the registry, I can confirm that the keys are not being created. I am running the code with Administrative rights, as that is the security context that VS is running in. Here is the code below:

**Registry.cpp**

```
int createRegistryKey(HKEY hiveHandle, LPCWSTR registryKeySequence) {

    HKEY keyHandle;

    if (RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, registryKeySequence, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &keyHandle, NULL)  != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Creating key/s failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        //return -1;

    }
    else {

        std::wcout << "Keys added successfuly" << std::endl;

    }

    RegCloseKey(keyHandle);
    RegCloseKey(hiveHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the code that calls the above function:

**fodhelperBypass.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "registry.h"

int main() {

    HKEY hiveHandle;

    /* Get handle to HKCU hive*/
    if (RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_SET_VALUE, &hiveHandle) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Opening hive failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        return -1;

    }
    else {

        std::wcout << "HKCU Hive opened successfully" << std::endl;

    }

    createRegistryKey(hiveHandle, L"\\SOFTWARE\\TestKey\\");
}
```

I believe I am using the correct access rights (`KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY`), but have changed to using `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`, however that has not seemed to help. The docs say that even if they key exists, that a handle should be returned, but that is not what is happening from what I can see.

I attempted to use the disposition argument to further understand what exactly was happening, however even in VS debug view, I was getting the value of `0x00000000`, which is meaningless when compared to the expected values stated in the documentation. `0x00000001L` for creation and `0x00000002L` for opened key. I even created an if, else if, else statement which first caught `disposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY` then `disposition == REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY` and the else statement catching cases where `disposition` was not equal to either value. It was the else statement which was executed every time I tested it.

Can anyone give me an idea of what I am missing here please?

Comment: What happens when passing in the actual error code returned, not `GetLastError()`? (And what is the raw error code, regardless?)

Comment: In the case(s) that "..return value is not ERROR_SUCCESS [and] the error text [from GetLastError() states that the operation had been executed successfully."; basically, first try to isolate if GetLastError() is complicating the observations, which can be done by comparing it to the return value and/or eliminating it entirely. (The hopefully result is that half the question can be eliminated or explained.)

Comment: GetLastError is useless here. The return value is the error code. What is it?

Comment: The raw error code returned is 161, not sure exactly where I look this up.

Comment: "If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h"  from the Microsoft documentation. So I use the `FormatMessage` function to get a meaningful error from this?

Comment: Start by looking the numeric value up in the docs. Search for windows error codes.

Comment: Yes, thank you. `ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME`, so I assume there is an issue with the data i'm passing to the `registryKeySequence` argument, and subsequently to `lpSubKey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems were occurring here; Firstly as noted by @David Heffernan, calling `GetLastError()` was not giving meaningful information about the error that was being encountered. When reading the Microsoft documentation originally, I did not read the information pertaining to error codes correctly.

> If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h. You can use the FormatMessage function with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag to get a generic description of the error.

Changing the error handling code, and providing  the return value of `RegCreateKeyExW` to `FormatMessage()`, instead of the error code from `GetLastError()`, yielded a more meaningful error: `ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME`(code 161).

```
int createRegistryKey(HKEY hiveHandle, LPCWSTR registryKeySequence) {

    HKEY keyHandle;

    LSTATUS result;
    result = RegCreateKeyExW(hiveHandle, registryKeySequence, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &keyHandle, NULL);
    
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, result, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Creating key/s failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        return -1;

    }
    else {

        std::wcout << "Keys added successfuly" << std::endl;

    }

    RegCloseKey(keyHandle);

    return 0;

}
```

After a little testing it became apparent that when providing the data to `lpSubKey`, the preceding backslashes were at issue:

```
createRegistryKey(hiveHandle, L"\\SOFTWARE\\TestKey\\");
```

After removing the double backslashes at the beggining of the string, the code executed as expected.